# expected value with coin

Tags: probability

A game is played where a fair coin is tossed three times. If one gets heads on all tosses, or tails on all tosses, then one is paid $14$. If any other result comes up then nothing is given out. If the cost of playing is $4$, what is the expected value of the amount of money you'll have at the end of the game?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You've got a $\frac28=\frac14$ chance of winning anything, and the only amount you can win is $\$14.$ What are your expected *winnings*, then? Now take into account the amount the game costs to play.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of all heads is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$, as is the probability of all tails.

So with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, we end up with a net win of $14-4$. With probability $\frac{3}{4}$, our "win" is $-4$.

It follows that our expected (mean) win is
$$\frac{1}{4}(14-4)+\frac{3}{4}(-4).$$

**Remarks:** The result is $-\frac{1}{2}$. Not too good! But a far better mean return than the standard lotteries.  And the more you play, then, on average, the more you lose.

Other analyses are possible. We pay $4$ dollars for the privilege of playing. Let $X$ be the **gross** amount that we win. This is $14$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, and $0$ with probability $\frac{3}{4}$. Thus $E(X)=\frac{14}{4}$. Finally, subtract the $4$ dollar ticket fee.

Comment: Why a fuuull answer?

Comment: @Did: Perhaps because I id not have enough time to give a short answer. Usually I don't do final computations, but wanted the $-\frac{1}{2}$ for rhetorical purposes.